# tex4ht ignores \input@path when looking for .4ht files?

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex

My situation is like this. I have a LaTeX file that I want to compile with pdflatex and tex4ht, which includes a package in another directory.

The file `bug.tex` contains:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\csdef{input@path}{{subdir/}}
\usepackage{mypackage}

\begin{document}

Test: \aaa.

\end{document}
```

The file `subdir/mypackage.sty` contains:

```
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}
\newcommand\aaa{AAA}
```

and the file `subdir/mypackage.4ht` contains:

```
\renewcommand\aaa{BBB}
```

When I compile with pdflatex, I get `Test: AAA.` in the output. But when I compile with make4ht, I still get `Test: AAA.` instead of `Test: BBB.`

(When the package is in the working directory, it works as expected.)

This indicates to me that, when using tex4ht, the redefinition of `input@path` occurs, but when including packages, tex4ht doesn't search it for `.4ht` files.

Can anyone help me work around this?

Of course, you are probably thinking that I'm doing this wrong, and I should put the package in my texmf, or set `$TEXINPUTS` correctly, and you would be right. But I have a complex project that I will need to share with colleagues who I can't expect to use make, so it would be much better if I can manage everything from within the tex files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tex4ht didn't support the `\input@path` by default. I've just added the support to the sources, so it should be included in TL soon. It was necessary to change some core macros that are not possible to modify using a `.cfg` file. So until the update is available, you can use the following workaround:

```
\InputIfFileExists{mypackage.4ht}{}{}
\Preamble{xhtml}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The `\InputIfFileExists` command searches the `\input@path` and includes the required file if it is found.

The result:

[image]

Comment: This is great, thank you for making this change so quickly!

Comment: @AlexWatson you are welcome. I didn't know about the `\input@path` before, so it was also something new for me :)